# Python Bar plot y axis display percentage

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have plotted a bar plot. I want the yaxis display values in percentage.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

df = 
     name    qty
0    Aple    200
1    Bana    67
2    Oran    10
3    Mang    8

ax=plt.bar(df['name'],df['qty'])
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
plt.show()
```

Present output:

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())

AttributeError: 'BarContainer' object has no attribute 'yaxis'
```

Comment: Wouldn't a pie chart make more sense if you want the `qty` values as percentages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.bar` does not return the axis instance. I think you mean:

```
ax = df.plot.bar(x='name',y='qty')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
```

Or

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(df['name'],df['qty'])
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
```

Output:

[image]

However, guessing from you trying to plot **percentage**, I think you want:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# note the division here
ax.bar(df['name'],df['qty']/df['qty'].sum())
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The second plot is what I am expecting.

Comment: @Mainland multiply with `100` :-)

Comment: @Mainland just realized that passing `xmax=1` to `PercentFormatter` also works without multiplying by `100`.

Comment: That's great. Let me try that.