# Add second y-axis with percentage in bar chart plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Given df:

```
  names  values  pct
0     a      10  0.1
1     b      20  0.2
2     c      70  0.7
```

Return a bar chart with secondary y-axis as a percentage (col pct)

Current code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'names':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'values':[10,20,70], 'pct':[0.1, 0.2, 0.7]})

# the figure 
fig = px.bar(df, x='names', y='values')
fig.show()
```

expected outcome:
[image]

**EDIT**: the solution provided works, is there a way to also add color to the bars, whilst not messing up the look (bar distance/alignment with xticks)

Here is my attempt modifying the solution provided:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = pd.DataFrame({'names':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'values':[10,20,70], 'pct':[0.1, 0.2, 0.7]})

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig1 = px.bar(df, x='names', y='values', color='names'  ) # added color 
fig2 = px.bar(df, x='names', y='pct', color='names')
 # plot singulalry all the bars provided. 
for i in range(len(fig1.data)): 
  fig.add_trace(fig1.data[i], secondary_y=False)
  fig.add_trace(a.data[i], secondary_y=True)

fig.update_layout(yaxis2=dict(tickvals=[0.1,0.2,0.7], tickformat='.1%', title_text='Secondary y-axis percentage'))
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(title_text='name'), yaxis=dict(title_text='values'))
fig.update_layout(bargap=0.0)
fig.show()
```

However it is producing double legend entry and misaligned x-axis labels

OUT:

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65948203/python-bar-plot-y-axis-display-percentage) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color of the bar chart by category, it is necessary to correspond with the markers in the graph object. in express, each is a bar chart by color, understood as 6 categorical variables, and I assume you are drawing abc categorical variables on top of each other. In the graph object, two graphs are drawn and the designated color is specified with a marker; it is set in hexadecimal format, but may be specified as red, blue, or green.

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'names':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'values':[10,20,70], 'pct':[0.1, 0.2, 0.7]})

colors = ['#636efa','#EF553B','#00cc96']

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['names'], y=df['values'], marker_color=colors, showlegend=False), secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['names'], y=df['pct'], marker_color=colors, showlegend=False), secondary_y=True)

fig.update_layout(yaxis2=dict(tickvals=[0.1,0.2,0.7], tickformat='.1%', title_text='Secondary y-axis percentage'))
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(title_text='name'), yaxis=dict(title_text='values'))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks your solution works, is there a way however to extend it to work with coloring the bars (based on name)? I have tried modifying your solution, however it seems to mess up the xaxis position and double the legend entry